# google check out success page redirection

Tags: payment-gateway, payment, google-checkout

Set Success page redirection in google checkout ?
i have already set callback URL to update the order status but how to redirect success page to my website after theu user paid by google checkout.

Comment: show some code, to illustrate your problem.

Comment: i got the answer already i think i dont need to show any codes this time. its common question..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no automatic re-direct for the buyer after the Google Checkout transaction finishes.

However, you can provide a link that the user can click and get back to your site after completing the order. See the continue_url paramenter:

http://code.google.com/apis/checkout/developer/Google_Checkout_HTML_API_Parameter_Reference.html#tag_continue-shopping-url